# !tensorboard --logdir= ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: tensorflow, syntax-error

I am new to tensorflow and I am learning it using a book called [Deep Learning with Applications Using Python Chatbots and Face, Object,and Speech Recognition
With TensorFlow and Keras](https://books.google.com.my/books/about/Deep_Learning_with_Applications_Using_Py.html?id=lQSKswEACAAJ&redir_esc=y).

On Chapter 1 page 6, there are lines of code:

[image]

And I typed the codes showed in the book exactly,

```
# Tensorboard can be used. It is optionalmy_
# Output graph can be seen on tensorboard
import os
merged = tf.summary.merge_all(key='summaries')
if not os.path.exists('tensorboard_logs/'):
    os.makedirs('tenosrboard_logs/')

my_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/home/manaswi/tenosrboard_logs/', sess.graph)

def TB(cleanup=False):
    import webbrowser
    webbrowser.open('http://127.0.1.1:6006')
    !tensorboard --logdir='/home/manaswi/tenosrboard_logs'

    if cleanup:
        !rm -R tensorboard_logs/


TB(1)   # Launch graph on tensorboard on your browser
```

But I get a syntax error when I run this code.

```
  File "c1_demo.py", line 26
    !tensorboard --logdir='/home/manaswi/tenosrboard_logs'
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Am I doing something wrong or is the code problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code of your book is written in a jupyter notebook and a special function of the jupyter notebook (jupyter magiv) is that the ! command executes a command in the console.

If you use another IDE use this function instead:

```
def TB(cleanup=False):
    import webbrowser
    os.system(tensorboard --logdir='/home/manaswi/tenosrboard_logs')
    webbrowser.open('http://127.0.1.1:6006')
```

And two additional things:

1. It is better to make your imports at the beginning of the code in case something went wrong
2. Tensorobard need a little bit time to start, so it is better to first create the the tensorboard and then open it